# How to display information from input fields in a bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So once the user has filled out their information and clicks submit I want to display the information in a bootstrap model with a confirmation button underneath.

This would be a summary of their information before it submitted to the database. So far here's what I've got:

```js
const text = document.getElementsByClassName("myText").innerHTML;

const modalBody = document.getElementById("bodyModal")

function submitText () {
  modalBody.innerHTML = text
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" class="myText">

<br>

<label>Age</label>
<input type="text" class="myText">

<br>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" onClick="submitText">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="bodyModal">
   
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
        function submitText(){
            var html="Your name is "+$("#name").val()+"<br>Your age is "+$("#age").val();
            $("#bodyModal").html(html);
        }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="myText" id="name"> <!-- i only added name id to this element -->

    <br>

    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" class="myText" id="age"> <!-- i only added age id to this element -->

    <br>

    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" onClick="submitText()"> <!-- here was an syntax error. you were calling method by uts name without () sign -->
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" id="bodyModal">
       
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 

const modalText = $("#modalText")

function submitText () {
var name = $("#myName").val();
var age = $("#myAge").val();
modalText.text("Hello " + name + " with " + age + " years old ");
}
```

```html
   

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" id="myName" class="myText">

<br />

<label>Age</label>
<input type="text" id="myAge" class="myText">

<br />

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" onClick="submitText()">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="bodyModal">
   <lable id="modalText"></lable>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of the input fields. I suggest giving the inputs two ids like this:

```
<label for="id1">Name</label>
<input type="text" class="myText" id="id1">

<label for="id2">Age</label>
<input type="text" class="myText" id=id2">
```

and then get their value with:

```
var name = document.getElementById("id1").value
var age = document.getElementById("id2").value
```

Finally, you can append the text you just got on the modal by doing so:

```
$("#bodyModal").html("<p>"+name+"</p><p>"+age+"</p>")
```